# Marker Bit In RTP for Voice Samples for codec like AMR and G729

Tags: rtp

I want to know the significance of Marker Bit in RTP for Voice packets and is here any RFC which tell that.

I know that the for the Video packets marker bit means last packet for the same image and hence, its the last packet with PTS time-stamp corresponding to image but for the Voice Packets for a codec say AMR-NB or G711 alaw or G729, the Marker Bit is usually false in each of the RTP packet.

So, do the meaning of Marker bit changes in this case of RTP packets??

Regards
Nitin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per RFC

> marker (M): 1 bit
>         The interpretation of the marker is defined by a profile.  It is
>         intended to allow significant events such as frame boundaries to
>         be marked in the packet stream.  A profile MAY define additional
>         marker bits or specify that there is no marker bit by changing the
>         number of bits in the payload type field .

My understanding is that for voice packet a data require for single frame (mostly for 20 ms) is not so big that we can send it in to more then 1 RTP packets.
So, for voice packet marker bit means start of new stream & consider time stamp from here.

When you look in to video packet (like H261, H263, ...) then single frame require multiple RTP packet. In that case marker bit represent end of single frame & after receiving that you can start parsing of whole frame.

This is also use for DTMF in RFC 2833 case where single event represented by multiple RTP packets.

Answer (score 5):

In audio codecs, if you will analyse the wireshark traces for any codec. Lets say AMR, you will have the following observations

For voice packets, the marker bits indicates the beginning of a talkspurt. Beginning of talkspurts are good opportunities to adjust the playout delay at the receiver to compensate for differences between the sender and receiver clock rates as well as changes in the network delay jitter. Packets during a talkspurt need to played out continuously, while listeners generally are not sensitive to slight variations in the durations of a pause.
The marker bit is a hint; the beginning of a talkspurt can also be computed by comparing the difference in timestamps and sequence numbers between two packets, assuming the timestamp clock rate is known.

Packets may arrive out of order, so that the packet with the marker bit is received after the second packet in the talkspurt. As long as the playout delay is longer than this reordering, the receiver can still perform delay adaptation. If not, it simply has to wait for the next talkspurt.

Source: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/rtp/faq.html#marker

The same thing can be read here too.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd944715(v=office.12).aspx